# Google Cloud Pub/Sub Emulator Deadline Excedeed

Tags: debugging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, development-environment, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

Recently my pubsub-emulator from google cloud ( https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator?hl=pt-br ) started hanging and not creating any topic, and when i do manage to publish a message in a existing topic, it either hangs and gives me DEADLINE_EXCEEDED or it takes a looong time to go...

Some more data: It started happening recently, here are my versions
Ubuntu 22.04

Google Cloud SDK 417.0.1
alpha 2023.02.08
beta 2023.02.08
bq 2.0.84
bundled-python3-unix 3.9.16
core 2023.02.08
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
gke-gcloud-auth-plugin 0.4.0
gsutil 5.19
pubsub-emulator 0.7.4

From my teammates, only Me and another co-worker are getting this behavior as well

I Already tried reinstalling my ubuntu, but it kept behaving like this...

Any lights or directions? I'm lost

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I had a communication problem between the emulator and the python commands for creating topics and subscriptions in this guide. The error returned was "google.api_core.exceptions.DeadlineExceeded: 504 Deadline Exceeded". I solved the problem by setting the `--host-port` parameter with the value `localhost:{somePort}` on starting the emulator. When I don't configure this parameter, the emulator sets the host `::1` and the example commands don't work.